# JavaScript hoisting variables from unexecuted branch

Tags: javascript, node.js

So i stumbled upon this behavior

```
var foo = "bar";

(function(){
   if(false) {
      var foo = "this truns the variable to undefined";
   }
   console.log(foo); // => undefined
})();
```

I understand the concept of hoisting. But shouldn't that only happen if the branch is executed?

```
var foo = "bar";

(function(){
   if(false) {
      foo = "this scenario is just fine";
   }
   console.log(foo); // => "bar"
})();
```

Comment: no.  it happens regardless of execution.

Comment: What do you mean by "presetting?"

Comment: in old IE yes, in newer browsers no. same for function statements btw...

Comment: @MattBall i mean it sets the variable to undefined by default even if it doesn't execute the statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to variable hoisting and the fact that locally declared variables hide global variable of the same name, your first block of code is equivalent to this:

```
var foo = "bar";

(function(){
   // define new local variable foo that hides the global one
   var foo;
   if(false) {
      foo = "this truns the variable to undefined";
   }
   console.log(foo); // => undefined, local foo has not been assigned a value
})();
```

Because of hoisting, the variable is defined at the start of the function block, regardless of execution path within the function.  Variables declared with `var` are scoped to the entire function and all definitions within the function are hoisted to the top of the function.

Variables defined with `let` (ES6 feature) are scoped to the block in which they are declared (still hoisted to the top of the block), but their definition is confined to the block in which they are declared, not the function in which they are declared.  So, if you used `let` instead of `var`, you would get a different result.

Thus, in your first block of code, you are declaring a new variable `foo` at the start of your function and that new declaration will hide the global definition by the same name such that any reference to `foo` inside that function will refer to the local one.

The conditional `if` statement only affects the assignment to `foo`, not the declaration of `foo`.  Thus, if the `if` statement does not execute, then `foo` is `undefined` since it was never assigned a value.

---

In your second code block, no new local `foo` variable is defined so all references to `foo` are simply referring to the global `foo` and since no new variable is declared, there is no hoisting.  This second code block behaves identially whether the IIFE function is there or not - it's just a simple `if` statement that decides whether to change the value of the global `foo` or not.

Comment: "Variables declared with var are scoped to the entire function and all definitions within the function are hoisted to the top of the function." That explained everything. Swapping var with let confirmed it. Thanks